# Linq: add objects from one list to another with an other type, (MVC, C#)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a "FindItemsResults`<Appointment>` list" which contains appointment objects.

I want to select "Start" property value and of all appointment objects from this List and save these values in an other list of type DateTime ... `List<DateTime> avaliableBookingDays`

```
List<DateTime> avaliableBookingDays = new List<DateTime>();
FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
IEnumerable<DateTime> res = from x in appointments
                            select new DateTime { (x.Start};
avaliableBookingDays.AddRange(res);
```

My LINQ exepression fails:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> res = from x in appointments
                          select new DateTime { (x.Start};
```

I get error, like that:

> Cannot inittialize type "DateTime" with a collection inittializer
>   because it do not implement  "System.Collections.IEnumerable"

The above-mentioned LINQ must do this:

```
foreach (var appObj in appointments)
{
    avaliableBookingDays.Add(appObj.Start);
}
```

Comment: Please put more effort into the formatting of your question - it's all over the place at the moment. Bear in mind that Stack Overflow is designed to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers. Ideally, provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not even going to compile

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> res = from x in appointments
                          select new DateTime { (x.Start};
```

because it has syntax errors ! In your select part, you are projecting to a new DateTime object and you have just an opening `(` , which does not make any sense!

I think you were getting the mentioned error when you had the closing bracket as well like

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> res = from x in appointments
                          select new DateTime { (x.Start)};
```

Here your code is trying (assume it was valid) to project the items from `appointments` collection to another collection of `DateTime` with some invalid syntax ! There is no need to use the `new` keyword here as you are not trying to create an object of a view model class/annonymous object since all you need is the Start property value.

**Solution**

Since `Start` is the `DateTime` type property, you want to select only that.

```
List<DateTime> avaliableBookingDays = (from x in appointments 
                                              select x.Start).ToList();
```

Or

```
List<DateTime> avaliableBookingDays = appointments.Select(a=>a.Start).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *project* items in sequence to some other type, use [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var avaliableBookingDays = appointments.Select(a => a.Start).ToList();
```

Note that there is no equivalent of `ToList()` operator in query syntax. So the best you can do is get `IEnumerable<DateTime>` result and convert it to list later:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> res = from x in appointments
                            select x.Start;

var avaliableBookingDays = res.ToList();
```

Also keep in mind - `DateTime` is a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You don't need to create new instance of this type to get a copy of appointment start time - copy will be created automatically.